# Vacuum or shock wave cased by beaming

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology, star-trek-transporter

Is anyone aware of it ever having been addressed that for a technology such as beaming to remove an object from an environment that is not a vacuum, that on removing it, there would be an instant collapse of a vacuum pocket where the object used to be. The inverse of that would be, provided that one was not "beaming the air out" then I would assume it gets pushed aside. If all this happens at any rate of high speed relating to that of electrons/photons one would have to guess that it causes at the very least a lot of noise...

One would think for this type of technology to work, there would have to be some sort of spatial pre/post processing. Likewise since the locations could and most likely would be moving in relation to one another (say if you were beaming to a planet from a space ship) if the source were not statically bound to the same physical / gravitational grasp (such as on the same planet) that it would not only have to be prepped ahead of time, but sustained and tracked at a potentially very fast rate.
The theory could even be weaponized, imagine if someone were to “beam” all the air out of a large building relatively instantly… or beam up a few cubic miles of dense atmosphere just to the left of a ship in orbit, how about a few tons of solar plasma onto a bridge? Matter is matter in that regard, but I digress…
There are things like Heisenberg compensators and inertial dampeners mentioned, has this seemingly obvious problem ever been directly addressed, and if so does anyone know of any specific show /. Episodes that did?

Comment: are you asking about real world physics applied to in-universe technology?

Comment: Also pretty darned dupey of [What happens to the air in the area, when things are transported or replicated?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73684/in-star-trek-does-being-transported-cause-your-ears-to-pop/85656#85656)

Comment: in-universe, the possible dupe question actually pretty well addresses the primary question which was "has any show/episode ever addressed this" I will admit it is a close question (wonder why it did not come up as I was typing this one?) Anyway, I get what the real world physics would be, a loud boom, and or puddle any time the wind blew.

Comment: I would think that the relative slow speed with which the transporter functions would prevent a fast vacuum collapse.  More like the air around slowly leaks in as the object is transported.